# MySQL suddenly 'crashed' but not stopped, mysqld_safe 100% cpu on CentOS 6

Tags: centos, centos6, server-crashes, mysql

Suddenly, today i see the website down.

Checking the cpu with "top" in command, i found the mysqld_Safe at the top using all of the cpu.

After some google i found some different solutions, i made a "reboot" that restarted everything and luckily everything came back on.

Now it's time to find out why this could happen and prevent it.

I check the mysql log and find this:

> ```
> Version: '5.1.73'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
> 140914 13:06:32 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Normal shutdown
>
> 140914 13:06:32 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
> 140914 13:06:32  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
> 140914 13:06:36  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 37356736
> 140914 13:06:36 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
>
> 140914 13:06:36 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
> 140914 13:07:07 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
> 140914 13:07:08  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
> 140914 13:07:08  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
> 140914 13:07:08  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 37356736
> 140914 13:07:08 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
> 140914 13:07:08 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
> Version: '5.1.73'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
> 141222 00:16:48 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
> 141222  0:16:49  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
> 141222  0:16:49  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
> InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
> InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
> 141222  0:16:49  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
> InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
> InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
> InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
> InnoDB: buffer...
> 141222  0:16:53  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 254950608
> 141222  0:16:53 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
> 141222  0:16:53 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
> Version: '5.1.73'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
> ```

And normally it look like this:

```
Version: '5.1.73'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
140913 23:44:50 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Normal shutdown

140913 23:44:50 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
140913 23:44:50  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
140913 23:44:51  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 36460121
140913 23:44:51 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140913 23:44:51 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
140913 23:45:18 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140913 23:45:18  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
140913 23:45:18  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140913 23:45:18  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 36460121
140913 23:45:18 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140913 23:45:18 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
```

Which clearly says something: That it didnt shut down normally and it started a crash recovery.

Now my question is:

1. Why is it even shutting down and starting? Why is there such "event" (as far as i understand?) - can this be disabled.
2. How can i prevent this crash? If there is any clear answer to this problem.

Comment: Is there free disk space left?

Comment: Yes. Looks like this currently while everything is up and running - http://i.gyazo.com/265bea81de986354bef99054c7799d6a.png